# Only show border when a div's height is greater than a certain amount

Tags: css

Suppose I have a `div` with a max height of `350px`.

Anything greater than this height and that `div` will `overflow` with a scroll bar.

Now if I want a border to show whenever there isn't a scroll bar, how would I achieve that.

Thanks.

Comment: in the question you said *is greater than* and in the description *whenever there isn't a scroll bar* ? can you explain by showing a screen

Comment: Not possible with only CSS. You will need javascript.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the question. Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it's possibl with just CSS.

However, You can make use of the `scrollHeight` property.

```js
var mydiv = document.querySelectorAll('.test');


for (var i = 0; i <= mydiv.length -1 ; i++) {
    var scrollHeight = mydiv[i].scrollHeight;
    if (scrollHeight < 350) 
    {
        mydiv[i].classList.add('border');
    }
}
```

```css
.test{
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.border{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
 I'm Boredered because i have no overflow <br>
 I'm Boredered because i have no overflow <br>
 I'm Boredered because i have no overflow <br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="test">
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
 I'm Borederless because i have overflow <br>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution as well. I was going to say something about the loop and algorithm efficiency, but that is trivial as the loop isn't needed for this to work. I know mine works, but this seems accurate as well, nice post!

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively straightforward using JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       if ($('#yourDiv').height() < 350) {//AS YOU ASK, UNDER 350PX
            $('#yourDiv').css("border-color", "red");
            $('#yourDiv').css("border-style", "solid");
       }
    });
</script>

<div id="yourDiv" style="height:349px;">
     <p> your div will have red border because of height being under 350px</p>
</div>
```

Comment: are you really serious? it's not how Javascript works, did you at least try this? https://jsfiddle.net/feokkus8/

Comment: Please try your code, it's not about JS solution or not  ... you code is completely wrong and invalid

Comment: Don't be that guy...I provided semi-complete code to help the OP figure out his solution as I was on my phone, which is still pretty standard seeing as no code was provided. My code can be used as is now, I have tested and it works as expected. It seems odd you decided to complain about the 'little things' when you could have just answered yourself...No worries do what you will, I suppose learning to code is not fun to you (which seems to be what we are all here to do)

Comment: `It seems odd you decided to complain about the 'little things'` --> I didn't complain, I pointed a complete wrong code and because I did this your correct it, and it was not little things ... by the way we can still see your history : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50223682/revisions so it's not fair to make me the *bad* guy because I corrected you. This is the purpose of this commnunity, you can learn code like you want but providing answer should be accurate and we comment to improve them

Comment: I'm sorry, but the main JQuery conditional has not changed, so yes little errors that take 5 seconds to fix are the "little things" (wrapping JQuery in proper tags and repositioning a div are trivial). As I said, no worries, it is now fixed. Take care :)

Comment: This doesn't even achieve what the OP asked.

Comment: Man trouble with this answer tonight, haha :) @ZohirSalak, how does my solution not accomplish this exact issue: **Now if I want a border to show whenever there isn't a scroll bar, how would I achieve that.** - The OP said a scroll bar appears after max height is reached at 350 and they want one to show when div is below the max size (i.e. 350px), which this answer solves using JS as partially noted in your own answer.

Comment: He want the dive to have a bored whenever there is no overflow, your solution adds the border no matter what

Comment: Well, @ZohirSalik what you say is not accurate with the question. The OP's div is set at max-height:350px, with this it seems that a scroll bar under 350px will not occur as there is no chance of overflow, so in that instance, my solution is completely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Use media query css :

```
#TestDiv{
        overflow: scroll;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    #TestDiv{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```